# Infinite animation for image changes in imageView ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, infinite-loop, uiviewanimation

I want to implement the next situation: step by step change image in uiImageView with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animation.

I've tried the following:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                      duration:2.0f
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                    animations:^{

                       imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
                      self.currentIndex ++;
                       if (self.currentIndex >2) self.currentIndex = 0;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    }];
```

But this does not even start animation. 
The only thing makes it work - use recursion for that purpose:

```
- (void) switchBckgroundWithIndex: (NSInteger) index imageView: (UIImageView*) imageView
{
    if (index >=[self.images count]) index = 0;
    @weakify(self)
    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                      duration:2.0f
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                    animations:^{
                        @strongify(self)
                       imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:index];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        @strongify(self)

                            [self switchBckgroundWithIndex:index+1 imageView:imageView];

                    }];

}
```

How can i change images repeatedly with those animation effect without using recursion? Please, help me to find solution

Comment: What's wrong with your second method? Why do you want to do it without recursion?

Comment: i have very strange artefact when i press back button - view not dissapearing smoothly (user see jerks)  until animations block executes. So, i find, that  recursion freeze ui somehow. Maybe, i need to stop all animations, but   [imageView .layer removeAllAnimations]; does not do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method for animating images in UIImageView

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];

    mutArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [mutArr addObject:@"b1@2x.png"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"b2@2x.png"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"b3@2x.png"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"b4@2x.png"];
   NSTimer *timerForImage = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(animateImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)animateImages
{

    imageCount = imageCount + 1;
    NSString *imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[mutArr objectAtIndex:imageCount]];
    if (imageCount==4)
    {
        imageCount=0;
    }
    _imgVw.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [_imgVw.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface abc ()
{
    int imgCount;
}
```

then in -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imgCount = 0;
    [self animateAllImages];
}

- (void)animateAllImages
{

    NSArray *animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image4"]];
    UIImage *image = [animationImages objectAtIndex:(imgCount % [animationImages count])];

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.animationImageView
                      duration:0.8f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.animationImageView.image = image;
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [self animateAllImages];
                        imgCount++;
                    }];
}
```